# Проблема в дереве массива категорий и под категорий

Tags: php

Проблема заключается в корректности составления массива категорий и под категорий.
Собственно сам код:

Метод создания самого дерева из массива:

```
public static function getTree($dataset){
    $tree = [];
    foreach ($dataset as $id => &$node) {
        if (!$node['parent_id'])
            $tree[$id] = &$node;
        else
            $dataset[$node['parent_id']]['childs'][$node['id']] = &$node;
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Метод, в котором используется созданное древо, и, соответственно, выводится результат:

```
 public static function getCategoriesList()
{
    $db = Db::getConnection();
    $result = $db->query('SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM category WHERE status = "1" ORDER BY sort_order, name ASC');

    $i = 0;
    $categoryList = [];
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        $categoryList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $categoryList[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
        $categoryList[$i]['parent_id'] = $row['parent_id'];
        $i++;
    }
    $tree = Category::getTree($categoryList);
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($tree, true).'</pre>';
    return true;
}
```

Таблица категорий

[image: Таблица категорий]

И дерево, которое получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы уверены, что у категории 1.1 `status = 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В методе `getCategoriesList` массив категории заполняется с последовательными номерами ключей (`$i`), а в методе `getTree` идет обращение к категориям из этого массива по идентификатору родительской категории (`$dataset[$node['parent_id']]`).
При заполнении массива следует указывать ключ категории `$row['id']`.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $categoryList[$row['id']]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $categoryList[$row['id']]['name'] = $row['name'];
    $categoryList[$row['id']]['parent_id'] = $row['parent_id'];
}
```

Comment: `$categoryList[$row['id']][] = $row`